# Securing data storage with .NET Facebook App (with Facebook C# SDK)

Tags: security, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I wanted to start a thread to understand practices people currently use to serialize user data in a Facebook (canvas) application running on .NET with the Facebook C# SDK.

Security: Has anyone exposed data endpoints that can be accessed in an AJAX-mechanism from a FB app? If so, how did you protect them? Seems like it would be simpler to access the data when doing a full postback in terms of security, but even there I'm not entirely sure about the security implications. I'm used to doing things with forms authentication so I'm pretty unsure of how to secure data in the FB context. Obviously not having passwords is nice but I still thought this was a worthwhile topic.

Thanks...

-Ben

Comment: Good question.  What's the attack vector?  Someone sniffing out the encrypted signed_request or user's OAuth token via a FireSheep-like tool and using it to spoof a POST via ajax to your endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on Facebook authentication, the best thing you can do is make sure the signed_request is valid, the Facebook C# SDK does this for you. (By valid, I mean that it originally came from Facebook) However, you cannot ensure it came from the person that the cookie says is the user. The signed_request could be intercepted since it is frequently sent over non SSL connections. This question contains two answers that are worth reading and should answer your question. [Facebook JS SDK: access_token in plain text and security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319710/facebook-js-sdk-access-token-in-plain-text-and-security/4321579#4321579)

Regarding exposing the ajax endpoint. Just make sure you pass the signed_request to the endpoint and use the FacebookApp class to read the session. This will ensure that it is valid. Here is more information on that topic: [Facebook C# SDK, AJAX in iFrame app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182064/facebook-c-sdk-ajax-in-iframe-app)

Comment: >the best thing you can do is make sure the signed_request is valid, the Facebook C# SDK does this for you..
_________
Does anyone have any experience incorperating the SDK with a web service? I've only seen examples of it being integrated into an ASP.NET webforms or MVC app.?

Comment: I've successfully got a WCF service which is accessible via GET, but I'm not sure if I can integrate the FB C# SDK with it. It seems that the logic in there for piecing together the user's data (request token, etc) does not expect everything to come into a specific method of a web method. Should I create parameters for things like the token? I'd just like the method to return the user's first name (as a getting started point, for now). Thanks in advance for any advice...